# What are the possible formats for attributes in Rust?

Tags: rust, attributes

I have come across attributes and observed that they sometimes come in different formats, but yet I was unable to find a place that actually explains these formats.

so far I have observed attributes of this form:

1. `#[attributes]` (e.g., `#[test]`)
2. `#[key=value]` (e.g., `#![crate_type = "lib"]`)
3. `#[method(param)]` (e.g., `#[cfg(test)]`)
4. `#[method(key=value)]` (e.g., `#[cfg(target_os = "linux")]`)

Question is, are these all the supported formats? And in what situation would you use one format over the other ones?

Comment: I believe [the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes.html) covers all of this.

Comment: This depends on the specific attribute being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes.html) covers the exact syntax, but what Rust will accept boils down to:

```rust
#[any::path]
#[any::path = some + expression]
#[any::path(pretty much anything)] // can also use {} and [] instead
```

From there, it's up to what the individual procedural macro the attribute is associated with to parse the attribute contents, and determine what is and is not valid.